# Excel.run, pass and return context as a variable, where does context come from?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, exceljs

I have a big Google Apps Script project working on Google Spreadsheets and I am trying to convert it to an office-js add-in that works on Excel Workbooks. I understand that it is good practice to put everything that will be calling excel specific functions (directly interacting with the workbook) into an `Excel.run()` function so it does a proper clean-up and no memory leaks occur. I also understand I should do `context.sync()` as little as possible to optimize performance.

Here are my questions, (I think some of them come from my incomplete grasp of how js works; these things GAS handled without me needing to question them) :

1a) When we put our block of code in

```
Excel.run(context => {
 //code that does stuff with context; 
context.sync();
});
```

where does the context come from? Is this equivalent to

```
Excel.run(()=> {
let context = new Excel.RequestContext; 
//code that does stuff with context; 
context.sync();
});
```

1b) Also, if context gets generated with every new function why would I ever `return context.sync()` and not just `context.sync()`?

2. Is a new, second context generated in this case and what happens to it?

```
function handle_error(e){//second context generated in case of error
let context=New Excel.RequestContext;
context.workbook.load('name');
await context.sync();
some_logging_function(context.workbook.name, e);
}
function data_func(some_data: Non-Excel-Interface): Other-Non-Excel-Interface{
   //manipulate data
   //in case of error
   handle_error(e);
   //continue with data massaging
   return altered_data;
}

Excel.run(context=>{ //first context
context.workbook.worksheets.getItem('Sheet1').getUsedRange().load('values');
context.sync();
let values = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem('Sheet1').getUsedRange().values;
let some_data: Non-Excel-Interface = {sheetName: 'Sheet1', data: values};
let new_vals = data_func(some_data);
context.workbook.worksheets.getItem('Sheet1').getUsedRange().values = new_vals.new_data;
context.sync();
});
```

3. If I put my main code inside Excel.run, then pass and return `context: Excel.RequestContext` and `range: Excel.Range` in other functions do I need  `Excel.run()` in those functions, too? In other words, should the code inside functions `a()` and `b()` be inside `Excel.run()`?

```
function a(rng: Excel.Range, values:string[][]):Excel.Range{
  rng.values = values;
  return rng;
}

function b(context: Excel.RequestContext): Excel.RequestContext{
  context.workbook.load('name');//load name property, but don't context.sync()
  return context;
}

Excel.run(async context=>{
  context = b(context);
  let rng =  context.workbook.worksheets.getItem('Sheet1').getUsedRange();
  rng.load('values');
  await context.sync();//values property and workbook name property must be available now
  rng = a(rng, [['aa', 'bb', 'cc']]);
  await context.sync();//new values must be available now
  console.log(context.workbook.name, rng.values);//should show the title of the workbook and the newly assigned values of the range
});
```

4. Also, what is the advantage of asynchronous functions if I have to explicitly wait every time I need a value? I mean, if I am going to use `context.sync()` sparingly, that means I use it only when I desperately need it, so it must always come with `await`. So why not make `context.sync()` synchronous by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer some of these questions and try to get some help for the others. I also recommend the book [Building Office Add-ins](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins) for an understanding of the Office JavaScript library. See this too, if you haven't already: [Application specific API model](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/application-specific-api-model).

1a. Yes. That's essentially correct. Under the hood, `Excel.run` creates an `Office.RequestContext` object and passes it to the batch function parameter. (But your two code blocks are not literally equivalent. You would not call `Excel.run` AND explicitly create a `RequestContext` object.)

1b. From skimming the book I linked to, I **think** that you have to `return` what the book calls the meta-promise so that the `Excel.run` can resolve the Promise that it returns. Here's an example from the book:

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
  var selectionRange = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
  selectionRange.format.fill.clear();

  selectionRange.load("values");
  
  return context.sync()
    .then(function () {
      var rowCount = selectionRange.values.length;
      var columnCount = selectionRange.values[0].length;
      for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
        for (var column = 0; column < columnCount; column ++) {
          if (selectionRange.values[row][column] > 50) {
            selectionRange.getCell(row, column)
             .format.fill.color = "yellow";
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .then(context.sync);
  
}).catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);
```

2. From skimming the book I linked to, I **think** that the answer is yes; the `Excel.run` always creates a new `context` object and passes it to the batch function. There are techniques and an override of `Excel.run` that enable you to pass an object created in one context to another call of `Excel.run`, but these are intended for use with independent calls of `Excel.run`, not nested calls, as in your case.
3. No. You should not call `Excel.run` inside `a` or `b`.
4. I **think** there are scenarios in which you would not need to await `context.sync`. For example, when all the code in the parent function that comes after the `context.sync` only affects the UI of a task pane and does not depend on reading any data from the current Office document. The good practice of minimizing calls of `context.sync` is because it requires a round-trip between the document and JavaScript runtime in which the add-in code is running (on the user's computer). This would be true regardless of whether `context.sync` is synchronous or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Rick. I got the book and I started reading it. I am in the process of testing my code. I will accept your thorough answer although I am not convinced by some parts. Maybe I will be convinced or will have the true answers when my code starts working :-D

Answer (score 0):

For 1a, here's one of the descriptions of how the Run function works which I'm getting from ScriptLab's intellisense:

> A function that takes in a RequestContext and returns a promise (typically, just the result of "context.sync()"). The context parameter facilitates requests to the Excel application. Since the Office add-in and the Excel application run in two different processes, the RequestContext is required to get access to the Excel object model from the add-in.

<s>In terms of 1b, I don't think so. RequestContext does not seem to be an object you can instantiate yourself.</s>

EDIT: actually it does look like this is possible. Please see below:

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async () => {
    let ctx:Excel.RequestContext = new Excel.RequestContext();
    let wb: Excel.Workbook = ctx.workbook
    let rang: Excel.Range = wb.getSelectedRange()
    rang.load("address")
    await ctx.sync()
    console.log(rang.address)
  });
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

I'd recommend against using this approach. Passing in anonymous functions, like in the original example, is very common in JavaScript. So this would likely be considered a bad practice.

Comment: I can do ```let ctx = new Excel.RequestContext;``` without a syntax error in typescript, doesn't that mean I can instantiate it myself?

Comment: @NincaTirtil Ah my mistake. It looks like I was incorrect. I tried using your method and received an error initially. I think it was because I forgot to load the properties I was trying to use. I will update my post.

Comment: Just to be clear, the quotation from Intellisense is not a description of the `run` method, it is a description of the batch function that is passed as a parameter to the `run` method.

Comment: Calling `Excel.run` and "new"ing up your own RequestContext object are alternative designs. You should not do BOTH. The best practice is to call `run` rather than create RequestContext objects directly.